# Request an Object on call an URL like https://xxx/stock?wsdl with AXIS2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

first of all I'm new to the topic using SOAP.

I want to make a request to a specified URL like "https://xxx/stock?wsdl"
The request has to use a method like: getFullStock(accessToken,...,...,...)

The only thing I have for authentification is an accessToken which has to be the first parameter of every method.
Is it right that I don't have to create a payload.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Andrew

Comment: so what is your problem? (`?wsdl` is usually reserved to get wsdl document)

Comment: My problem is that I don't have a clue how manage such a request.

Comment: then learn about webservices first. Btw, in SOAP request parameters are passed not by URI parameters, but in envelope of a request.